# How to wrap text label in mat-slide-toggle (Angular Material)

Tags: css, angular, sass, material-ui, angular-material

I want to use the mat-slide-toggle, but have the title wrap (as it's a bit long). How can I achieve that. I just want to have the title wrap and keep its default place to the right of the toggle

```
<mat-slide-toggle class="slider">A really long title wrapped</mat-slide-toggle>
```

I tried `flex-wrap` but doesn't work

```
.slider {
  flex-wrap: wrap !important;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

You can see how the wording is coming outside the container
[image]

Comment: Try `word-wrap` instead

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you will have to drill down to the text content using ::ng-deep.

If you did not know, 'mat' elements are usually comprised of various other elements and grouped together. For example, here is what  looks like under the hood.

[image]

In this case, `<span class=""mat-slide-toggle-content></span>` is actually where the text is located. So while you are applying text-wrap to 'slider' class, it is not actually affecting the correct element. We can see that this class is responsible for the lack of text-wrapping.

[image]

To drill down into these styles you can use ::ng-deep. So instead of what you are trying, try something like:

```
::ng-deep .mat-slide-toggle-label .mat-slide-toggle-content {
     white-space: normal;
     overflow: visible;
     text-overflow: unset;
}
```